# Kubernetes Ingress/nginx pod specific value

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm very new to Kubernetes and still learning how to use LB, ingress, etc. Currently, I'm trying to set pod-specific value(config) for each host. Looks like in ingress yaml spec, it can read config from values. But I would like to read ingress spec, e.g. host, in Values.yaml.

For example, I have two hosts

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: service-A.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myservicea
          servicePort: 80
  - host: service-B.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myserviceb
          servicePort: 80
```

And I have two variables in values.yaml:

```
var1: aaa
var2: bbb
```

I want to pass

1. var1 to service-A.com/myservicea
2. var2 to service-B.com/myserviceb

or pass both, but the application must be able to identify what host it is, then it can use the right variable.

Is there any configuration/apis available to use for this purpose?

Comment: You need to create secret and use as env https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

Comment: Could you elaborate exactly what you want to achieve? Ingress is responsible for HTTP traffic redirections. Do you want to apply specific configuration for specific deployment? If so you can use [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) or [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) if this is sensitive data like passwords. You want to use `values.yaml` did you read about [Helm](https://helm.sh/) and want to apply it in your cluster?

Comment: @PjoterS, Thanks! I just read about ConfigMap which would help. However, it won't solve my issue. I was able to expose env vars to pods. But pods need to know which var to use since it is not a stateless LB service.  Each pod will use different values for the same kind of job. And that host, e.g. serviceA, must tie to the exact same value for each deployment. E.g. www.serviceA.com/process, it should read varA, and do the logic with varA, and render the result back. I found out I was able to set StatefulSet metadata.name (service name) as an env var. So the logic can be done in application.

Comment: Im still confused what you want to achieve. You have pod with specific env variable and you want (based on that env) to route this specific pod to host including this env var? Do you want to rout traffic based on this env var? You mention you want to pass `var1 to service-A.com/myservicea`. You mean add env variable when pod will be redirected to this service or more like routing based on this env?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can create a secret.

```
kubectl create secret generic CUSTOM_VAR\
      --from-literal=VAR_A=aaa\
      --from-literal=VAR_B=bbb
```

This is how you can access the secrets in you deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: myservicea-depl
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: myservice
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: myservice
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: myservice
              image: user/myservicea
              env:
                - name: VAR_A
                  value: aaa // this way you directly pass values here
                - name: VAR_A // this way you can store this as secret in k8s
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: CUSTOM_VAR
                      key: VAR_A
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is pretty close to what I want.